The variation of an absolutely continuous function that is of finite variation is absolutely continuous.
I want to prove the following:

Proposition$\quad$ If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous and of finite variation, then $V_F$ is absolutely continuous.

Here is my attempt so far:

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the absolute continuity of $F$, we can choose a $\delta$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(s_i)|<\epsilon$ holds whenever $\{(s_i,t_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ is a finite sequence of disjoint open intervals for which $\sum_{i=1}^n(t_i-s_i)<\delta$. Then each finite sequence $\{(u_j,v_j)\}_{j=i}^m$ of disjoint open subintervals of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n(s_i,t_i)$ satisfies $\sum_{j=1}^m(v_j-u_j)<\delta$ and so satisfies $\sum_{j=1}^m|F(v_j)-F(u_j)|<\epsilon$.

From here I want to write:

Since
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^nV_F[s_i,t_i] = \sup\left\{\sum_{j=1}^m|F(v_j)-F(u_j)|:\ \text{$\{(u_j,v_j)\}_{j=1}^m$ is a finite sequence of disjoint open subintervals of $\bigcup_{i=1}^n(s_i,t_i)$}\right\},
\end{align*}
we have that $\sum_{i=1}^nV_F[s_i,t_i]\leq\epsilon$, and thus
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|V_F(t_i)-V_F(s_i)| = \sum_{i=1}^nV_F[s_i,t_i] \leq \epsilon.
$$

But I am not sure if the "supremum step" is correct. (It intuitively makes sense to me, but I am not sure how prove it formally.) Could someone please help me out? Thank you very much in advance!

I realized that perhaps the following would make the question more clear:

Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $[a,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    a \leq t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F[a,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $[a,b]$} is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F[a,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $[a,b]$ if $V_F[a,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes the interval $(-\infty,b]$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n \leq b.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,b]$, the variation of $F$ over $(-\infty,b]$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,b] = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{i=0}^{n}\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) on $(-\infty,b]$ if $V_F(-\infty,b]$ is finite.


Definition$\quad$ Suppose that $F$ is a real-valued function whose domain includes $\mathbb{R}$. Let $\mathscr{S}$ be the collection of finite sequences $\{t_i\}_{i=0}^n$ such that
\begin{align*}
    -\infty < t_0 < t_1 < \dots < t_n < +\infty.
\end{align*}
Then $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$, the variation of $F$ over $\mathbb{R}$, is defined by
\begin{align*}
    V_F(-\infty,+\infty) = \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^n|F(t_i)-F(t_{i-1})|:\{t_i\}_{t=0}^n\in\mathscr{S}\right\}.
\end{align*}
The function $F$ is of finite variation (or of bounded variation) if $V_F(-\infty,+\infty)$ is finite. If $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation, then the variation of $F$ is the function $V_F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $V_F(x)=V_F(-\infty,x]$.

In addition, we have:

Proposition$\quad$ Suppose that $F:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is of finite variation. If $-\infty<a<b<+\infty$, then
\begin{align}
    V_F(-\infty,b] = V_F(-\infty,a]+V_F[a,b].
\end{align}


You define $V_F(x)$ via $V_F(-\infty,x]$, but you have not defined the latter.

@amsmath I updated the definitions.

Another approach: if $f$ is $AC$ of finite variation, then $f'$ is in $L^1(\mathbf{R})$. Since $V_F(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x |f'(t)|\ dt$, it follows that $V_F$ is absolutely continuous.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $\{(t_i,s_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be disjoint intervals such that $\sum_{i=1}^n|t_i-s_i| < \delta$ (same $\delta$ as for $F$). For each $i$ we find $t_i = u_0^i < \dots < u_{m_i}^i = s_i$ such that
$$
V_F[t_i,s_i]\le\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}|F(u_j^i)-F(u_{j-1}^i)| + \frac\varepsilon n.
$$
Now, $\{(u_{j-1}^i,u_j^i) : i=1,\ldots,n,\,j=0,\ldots,m_i\}$ consists of disjoint open intervals with $\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=0}^{m_i}(u_j^i - u_{j-1}^i) < \delta$. Finally, using the absolute continuity of $F$, we see that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nV_F[t_i,s_i] = \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg[\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}|F(u_j^i)-F(u_{j-1}^i)| + \frac\varepsilon n\bigg]\le 2\varepsilon.
$$
